# Insert SEO friendly dynamic data into HTML without Javascript

Tags: html, seo

I have some static websites. By static I mean all the pages are simple HTML without JavaScript (all the data are hard-coded).

I have a server side program that creates dynamic data that I'd like to insert into my static sites. By dynamic I mean the data changes very often.

How should I do this?

Here is a scenario: On the server side my program generates the current time-stamp in every millisecond. When a user open one of my static sites the page gets the current time-stamp from the server and render it. 
I'd like it to work with search engines, so I can't use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the HTML structure client side without Javascript, so your solution is to add some handler server side for files with .htm and .html extensions.

About JS: Please note that most spiders (if not all) won't be able to see data rendered by javascript since most of them are analyzing the plain HTML that is returned by the server.